# Aggregate data frame by column, filtering on a different column

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr, summarize

I want to aggregate some columns of a data frame using a factor (`group` in the example) but I want to use only the rows with the highest values in a different column (`time` in the example)

```
df=data.frame(group=c(rep('a',5),rep('b',5)),
           time=c(1:5,2:6),
           V1=c(1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1),
           V2=c(2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5))
```

I know how to do it using `ddply` but it's pretty slow

```
ddply(df,'group',summarize,
      V1=sum(V1[order(time,decreasing = T)[1:2]]),
      V2=sum(V2[order(time,decreasing = T)[1:2]]))

"group" "V1"    "V2"
"a" 4   2
"b" 2   6
```

Is there a faster way to do it (`aggregate` or `data.table`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `arrange` the data by `time`, `group_by` `time` and `sum` top 2 values using `tail`.

This can be done using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(group, time) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(V1:V2), ~sum(tail(., 2)))

#  group    V1    V2
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         4     2
#2 b         2     6
```

and in `data.table` as :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(group, time), lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(tail(x, 2))), 
          .SDcols = c('V1', 'V2'), group]
```